# AWS S3 upload with unicode in key fails .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

Having issues uploading keys that contain non-ascii characters and some punctuation characters to Amazon S3 using .NET 4.5.  The same code works fine under .NET 4.0 but fails when compiled with 4.5 with this exception:

> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does
>   not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing
>   method.

A few example failing keys:

```
fail-é-(
fail-é-)
fail-é-[
```

and a few good keys:

```
ok-é-x
ok-é-é
ok-(-)
```

Pick a key from the failing keys and a simple put object fails with this sample C# code:

```
using Amazon.S3.Model;

// ...

var s3key = "...";
var s3secret = "...";
var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(s3key, s3secret);
var bucketName = "unicode-test";

var key = "fail-é-(";

client.PutObject(new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = key,
        ContentBody = "TEST CONTENT"
    });
```

What is the new 4.5 + AWSSDK magic that I need to add?

ps. The issue is the same in both a console app and a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to comment, but someone may find it helpful still.

I had the same issue with AWS .NET 4.5 SDK.
The solution was to set the Signature Version to V2 explicitly:

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();                  
config.SignatureVersion = "2";
...
```